# Excel Character Formula for a Column?

Tags: excel

I wasn't really sure how to google or even ask this as a question, so this is the best way to explain it:

Whats the best way to make a String repeat +1

So lets say for a column I have:
CB-001
CB-002
CB-003....etcc

is there any formula to make it just CB-00X and then every row make X+1?

Thanks, (Im sure this has been asked before, but I'm not even sure what you would call it?)

Comment: you want to `auto-increment` column names, but you have specific requirements.  You could likely create a macro to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a combination of `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `TEXT`

```
=LEFT(A1,3)&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,3)+1,"000")
```

So, if I `CB-001` is in `A1`, and place the formula in `A2` and drag it down, it yields the following.

```
CB-001
CB-002
CB-003
CB-004
CB-005
CB-006
CB-007
CB-008
CB-009
CB-010
```

- `LEFT(A1,3)` Will get the prefix that you want to keep
- `RIGHT(A1,3)+1` Will get the number portion and increment by 1
- `TEXT(value, "000")` will pad the number so it displays at least three digits.
- `&` Will concatenate the two together to give you your next result.